# Add a smooth slide to a div that changes position on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used a script that 'Sticks a div at top of page' after scrolling, written by [livibetter](https://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/).

```
<script>
function sticky_relocate() {
 var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
 var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
 if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
 } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
 }
}

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
  sticky_relocate();
});
```

Which is close to what I am looking for. But I need to have the div and its contents end up 'Y' pixels down the page rather than at the very top of the page.

[like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Steven_Joiner/uhu1b72z/).

I would like the div to smoothly slide into position rather than a sudden jump as it is currently.

Any help for this Javascript/jQuery novice would be most appreciated. ;-)

Comment: What's your approach? 
Waiting for others to work on this kind of solution is not adequate in this environment.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense for the element to never reach the top of the page? https://jsfiddle.net/uhu1b72z/1/

Comment: Thanks Turnip, yes I suppose it does make more sense. Clearly I was over complicating this. a habit of mine in this new environment I have found myself in.